# Trying to integrate a Calendar library that was built for versions of iOS before iOS5 into my new project in XCode 4 using iOS5 - How to port?

Tags: ios, calendar, automatic-ref-counting

I need a calendar View in my iOS 5 project. I found this [Library](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) on github that is exactly what I need. However, it was bult for versions of iOS previous to iOS5.

As a preliminary step of integration, I downloaded the zip files and converted the projects into ARC compatible iOS 5 project using the feature in XCode 4 under "refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC" to do this. I bult that project and it built fine in iOS5.

Now I m following the instructions on how to integrate the files in my existing project and here is what I did so far:
1) I created a new group in my project called "ImportedFiles"
2) I clicked on "add files" for this group, and selected the entire set of files of the calendar project that I had downloaded and unzipped and copied them into my project.See here:

[image]

3) Then after looking at the instructions on the download site. Specifically instruction #3 They ask you to link the files. This is where I gave up. I couldn't figure out what to do.

Could someone please help me in this integration process.

I would like to know
1) If what I have done so far is correct
2) How do I proceed with this after I have copied the files into my test project?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the project in the Navigator, then select the target.  Under Build Phases, you want to add in the library under the Link Binary With Libraries section.

Furthermore, to have Xcode to help with autofill, you may want to add the absolute path of where the header files are stored in your project to the User Header Search Paths under Build Settings.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible you could give me more specific steps. I do know I need to go to the buildphases and link from there. But the problem is this is not a compiled binary. These are files and if you read the instruction on GitHub ie: instruction #3 it states the steps but , what is the equivalent of those steps in XCode 4?

Please help.

Comment: Ok, I created a project.  I pulled the entire directory klazuka-Kal-b2e164c into my project.  I then selected my project in the navigator, and the like-named target to the right.  In Build Phases, under Link... I hit the "plus" button.  In that menu, listed under Workspace, was libKal.a.  I added that.  A few warnings popped up, suggesting updating certain aspects, which I accepted.  From there, I was able to import Kal headers into my project classes and use its classes as desired.